# How about attaching a boolean value within the if condition?

Tags: javascript

I found the following javascript code:

```
function testScope(){
    var myTest = true;
    if(true){
        var myTest = "I am changed!"
    }
}
testScope(); // will alert "I am changed!"
```

I'm really very confused the boolean is attached in if condition rather than `if(myTest)`, so I thought it might be mistake but when changed false in if condition `if(false)` it is alerting true. I've never seen like this before.

Comment: variable name is same. var myTest = true;  var myTest = "I am changed!"

Comment: So, what is the problem you are facing here?

Comment: See question title, i.e. I need more desc about this.

Comment: how will it alert anything when there is no `alert()` statement?

Comment: I don't understand your question, `if(true)` will always be true since it's not a variable

Comment: Yeah! that's why I'm confused and asked here.

Comment: Why is it confusing? That's how it is. True is not assigned, so it's a static condition

Comment: So, to what it will test for true or false? it's obviously not pointing to myTest

Comment: In a book "object oriented javascript"

Comment: @C-link are you sure this wasn't an example of what *not* to do? I've seen people use things like `if (false)` as a sort of block comment, but never something like this.

Comment: @C-link, interesting comment from author [on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-JavaScript-Stoyan-Stefanov-ebook/dp/B0057UNEJC). Sounds like there may have been some problems in publication with some edition of that book.

Comment: um, it's titled under **Scoping in JavaScript**

Comment: @C-link are you *sure* it's not a counter-example, trying to explain that there is no block-local scope in JS, only function-local (as in jasonscript's answer)?

Comment: I just see ... it's saying block-level scoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're focusing on the wrong part of the code snippet: it's not trying to demonstrate the `if(true)` statement. It is trying to show how javascript handles variable declarations

```
function testScope(){
    var myTest = true;                 // <- variable declared at function level
    if(true){
        var myTest = "I am changed!"   // <- variable declared at 'if' block level
    }
}
testScope(); // will alert "I am changed!"
```

Because javascript only has function scoped variables, this code snippet is showing that the `myTest` variable is being set to 'I am changed!' even though it is being declared as an inner-variable. In some other languages (e.g. C#, this would be a compile time error)

The `if(true)` condition is to ensure that the if block code will always execute.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it's easy to get stuck on the wrong part of the example and you just need a quick explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

you only distinguish between global-scope and function-scope.
if-conditions and loops do not have an own scope, so when the condition in the if-statement is true, the function-scope variable myTest will be overwritten (because it is redefined in the same scope)

Answer (score 0):

`if(true)` should be true always becuase it's **not a variable**

**Boolean object:**

The Boolean object represents two values: `true` or `false`.

If the Boolean object has no initial value, or if the passed value is one of the following:

```
0
-0
null
""
false
undefined
NaN
```

the object is set to false. For any other value it is set to true (even with the string "false")!

Answer (score 0):

The reason `if(true)` evaluates to true is because it's the "result" of a conditional statement.

```
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
if (x < y) { ... }
```

`x` is less than `y`, so it comes down to

```
if (true)
```

So you can boil it down to a static condition since there is no variable conditioning going on.